# Throw Error for RDS ScalingConfiguration parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

We use this function in a AWS Lambda, but we're having the error of

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference: errorString
> [{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.24.0/lambda/errors.go","line":39,"label":"lambdaPanicResponse"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.24.0/lambda/function.go","line":36,"label":"(Function).Invoke.func1"},{"path":"runtime/panic.go","line":679,"label":"gopanic"},{"path":"runtime/panic.go","line":199,"label":"panicmem"},{"path":"runtime/signal_unix.go","line":394,"label":"sigpanic"},{"path":"Lamda/main.go","line":55,"label":"HandlerAcus"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":460,"label":"Value.call"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":321,"label":"Value.Call"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.24.0/lambda/handler.go","line":124,"label":"NewHandler.func1"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.24.0/lambda/handler.go","line":24,"label":"lambdaHandler.Invoke"},{"path":"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.24.0/lambda/function.go","line":64,"label":"(Function).Invoke"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":460,"label":"Value.call"},{"path":"reflect/value.go","line":321,"label":"Value.Call"},{"path":"net/rpc/server.go","line":377,"label":"(*service).call"},{"path":"runtime/asm_amd64.s","line":1357,"label":"goexit"}]

the code is

```
func main() {
    lambda.Start(proceso)
}

func proceso(parametros Parametros) {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-east-1"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    acusN32 := int32(parametros.Acus)

    svc := rds.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // Configura el objeto rds.ModifyCurrentDBClusterCapacityInput
    var param rds.ModifyDBClusterInput
    param.ScalingConfiguration.MinCapacity = &acusN32
    param.DBClusterIdentifier = &parametros.Instancia

    /* resp, err := svc.ModifyCurrentDBClusterCapacity(context.TODO(), &param) */
    resp, err := svc.ModifyDBCluster(context.TODO(),  &param)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("falló al modificar ACUS, %v", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Los ACUS de " + *&parametros.Instancia + " quedaron seteados en " + string(*resp.DBCluster.Capacity))
    }
}
```

The line error is this

```
var param rds.ModifyDBClusterInput
    param.ScalingConfiguration.MinCapacity = &acusN32
    param.DBClusterIdentifier = &parametros.Instancia`
```

What's Wrong ?

&acusN32 is a valid int32 pointer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `parametros` is `nil` in you case, so you have to add something like this:

```
func proceso(parametros Parametros) {
  if parametros == nil {
     // log error & return
  }
  ...
```